# subsetting and averaging values in a data set

Tags: r, subset, mean

I'm currently working with preinstalled data set `CO2`, using the `subset()` function. I need to get the mean for the chilled treatments, but I'm having issues writing it.
I've tried code like `mean(subset(data,Treatment=chilled))` but that was definitely wrong.

Some solutions I've tried were

```
mean(subset(treatment,chilled))
subset(treatment,chilled)
chilled <- subset(mean,treatment=chilled)
```

all came back with wrong answers.

Comment: I think you need `aggregate` instead of  `subset`. Provide a small reproducible example and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: In my assignment, I must use a subset. :(

Comment: When you submit your assignment you ought to indicate that you got help on Stack Overflow ...

Answer (score 1):

As the `uptake` variable is the most obvious response variable, you probably want something like

```r
mean(subset(CO2, Treatment == "chilled")$uptake)
```

- you need the `==` here to check for equality, and you need to check against a string value ("chilled")
- you can't take the mean of the whole data frame, you have to pick out a numeric variable (using `$` or `[[`)